# Axios not sending header on patch but does on get-requests

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm making a web app that uses Axios. 
I have a base service class that has an interceptor that will add the access token to each request. However, the interceptor wont add the token on my PATCH request, only on the GET request.

My base api service

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default class api {

  constructor (path) {
    this.api = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'http://localhost:1337/' + path
    })

    this.api.interceptors.request.use(config => {
      config.headers['x-access-token'] = localStorage.getItem('jwt-token')
      return config
    })

    this.api.interceptors.response.use(undefined, (err) => {
      if (err.response.status === 401) {
        throw err
      } else {
        throw err
      }
    })
  }
}
```

The service that extends the base

```
import Api from './api'

export default class ProfileService extends Api {
  constructor () {
    super('profile/')
  }

  me () {
    return this.api.get('/me')
  }

  updateProfile (uuid, data) {
    return this.api.patch('/' + uuid, data)
  }

}
```

Axios does add the token to PATCH requests if I make a global interceptor like this:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['x-access-token'] = localStorage.getItem('jwt-token');
```

I do not want to do this though, as it will send the token to other servers as well.

Any ideas on why my interceptor wont add the token when specified per instance? Is this a bug with Axios?

The OPTIONS-request has the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-access-token,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,OPTIONS
```

Thanks in advance,

Axel

Comment: Don't know if it's a bug in Axios, but on [their github page](https://github.com/axios/axios) there's a method `transformRequest` which states "This is only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', and 'PATCH'".  Try using `transformRequest` to add your header for PATCH requests.  Might be a work-around until you figure out why the interceptor isn't working (I suggest reporting this to the axios team).

Comment: This was completely my fault, forgot to actually use the service, and not axios directly, in my component.... Took me way longer than I want to admit.